# Geotools FeatureReader - Initial memory consumption problem

Tags: postgis, geotools

I am using a `FeatureReader` to access features from a PostGis source using the following code:

```
DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(postgisParams);

Transaction transaction =  new DefaultTransaction();
Query query = new Query("MyTableName"); // DefaultQuery for GT 2.4.5!

FeatureReader reader = dataStore.getFeatureReader(query, transaction);
```

The table contains ~1.150.000 features. I updated the Geotools version from `2.4.5` to `18.2`. I used Java VisualVM to record the memory consumption.

No memory issues using the old version (2.4.5):

[image]

Same code and newer GT version (18.2):

[image]

When having a look at the images above you can see that the FeatureReader using GT version 18.2 initially allocates ~800MB memory (for ~1.150.000 features) which is a lot more than ~50MB (using the older GT version 5.4.2).

To be more precise about the problem: The code is working in both versions. BUT the problem is the initial memory consumption when creating (and holding) the `FeatureReader`. I made the following observations:

- The memory consumption is growing with the number of requested features.
- The memory consumption decreases after features are read and the reader is closed (no GC problem).
- In both cases the used FeatureReader class is  `org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader`

I do not want to load the features into memory. Is there a more performant way (regarding memory consumption) to use `FeatureReader` (or something equivalent) with newer versions of Geotools ?

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: The memory consumption is way too high? Especially compared to the old behaviour. How can I achieve similar memory consumption as using GT 2.4.5?

Comment: Look at your gc settings, but geotools will try to use as much as possible to speed up requests

Comment: The memory consumption is high when the reader is created. As soon the features are read and the reader is closed the garbage collection cleans up as expected. The main problem here is the initial memory consumption that grows with the number of requested features. This was obviously not the case with the old Geotools version. An initial memory consumption of ~800MB (for ~1.150.000 features) is quite strange compared to ~50MB. Seems that the newer implementation loads the features into memory whereas the old version did not.

Comment: I also reported the issue: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the **parameter "fetch size"** solves this issue for JDBC connections!

```
params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.FETCHSIZE.key, 2000); // Number of records to read
```

The value of 2000 seemed to be a good tradeoff in my case (feature fetch duration of 25 seconds for ~1.150.000 features):

[image]